# I want to play if first sound is completed the invoke to play second

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is my next and previous button function.  Here i want to play the first sound after that want to play second and so on.

**Problem Occurs**: the first sound is interupted and the 2nd sound is invoked to play. Ideally, I want the second sound to only start if and only if the first sound has completed.

```
if (counter <= [textStr count]) {
  counter++;
  NSLog(@"%i", counter);

  [stgImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageStr objectAtIndex:counter]]];
  stgText1.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr objectAtIndex:counter]];

  if (counter == 0) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(300, 120, 263, 263);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"eggDance" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }
  if(counter == 1) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(330, 150, 147, 209);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clownDance" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }
  if(counter == 2) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(380, 120, 104, 237);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drumperDrum" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }
  if(counter == 3) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(370, 120, 154, 253);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ladyPlay" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }
  if(counter == 4) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(330, 60, 241, 298);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boyPlayBall" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }
  if(counter == 5) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(350, 90, 144, 262);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boyPlayBalloons" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }
  if(counter == 6) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(340, 160, 138, 198);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boyRideCycle" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }
  if(counter == 7) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(320, 40, 201, 317);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"girlBlowBubbles" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }
  if(counter == 8) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(330, 70, 202, 268);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dollDance" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }
  if(counter == 9) {
    stgImage1.frame = CGRectMake(320, 100, 241, 245);
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chickenDance" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
  }

  if (counter >= 10) {
     counter = 0;
     [self initArray];

  }
}
```

help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
- (void) startPlaying{
counter = 0;
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"eggDance" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.delegate = self;

[player play];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
   //start playing next sound
}
```